# How to write a Base contract extendable by other contracts in Corda

Tags: kotlin, blockchain, corda

I need to build a cordapp with reusable/extendable contract (interface)

I have decided to build a re-usable Cordapp platform that will serve the need of multiple co-operates with minimal updates (per co-operate) when necessary.

I plan to achieve this by creating base classes for the States and Contracts which shall contain every possible common properties for each kind of Payment Instrument and will be extended by other regular States and Contracts. As for the flows, I can have all basic generic flows ready. Customized flows can then be written upon requirement and this (hopefully) would only be minimal additions to be made upfront.

In order to achieve the above plans, I recently tried it out with a test Cordapp.

For States, I observed that I could possibly have a base (Interface) State with all possible common parameters (for a particular Payment Instrument), which can then be extended by other regular States as planned.

For Contracts, I had a bit of challenge.

While having an Interface Contract IXContract being extended (by an open class) XContract, I got a transaction error “Contract verification failed: Required com.template.contracts.IXContract.Commands command, contract: com.template.contracts.XContract”. This seem to be caused by a conflict in contracts being used by a single XState.

I also modified the code to having IXContract as an open class and and XContract as abstract class. This returned a successful transaction, however the invalid rule in the IXContract was not caught and this is not the expected behavior of the project.

To avoid contract conflicts, I tried the usual programming style of simple classes. With base class IXContract, this time not extending the Contract interface (which makes it not a contract class), but  contains a BaseContract method with contract rules. I then autowired this class in the regular XContract class (still extending the contract interface) and called the BaseContract method to apply the contract rule within it. This was tested successfully and the contract rules were caught as required. For more assurance, the flow was adjusted to align with the contract rules and the test transaction was then successful.

I however noted that this would obviously lead to us having a huge file of BaseContract class in future, but these have been
our test trials so far.

Is this a good route towards implementing a reliable project with no possible risk upfront?

Kindly advice on a best way to achieve it if you can already foresee a disadvantage in our test trials.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend against creating sub contract interfaces only because you may run into problems in corda that you don't expect. Almost all the cordapps I've ever seen do not have a need for a more specific contract interface that can still apply to multiple state types. I'd just go through the pain of having a larger contract class, there may be plenty of other ways.

Assuming you still want to do this, then just watch the abstractions carefully, but kotlin will let you do this, just make sure to implement the contract interface correctly and you should be able to get it to work without too much pain.

```
interface Named {
    val name: String
}

interface Person : Named {
    val firstName: String
    val lastName: String

    override val name: String get() = "$firstName $lastName"
}
```

So in the case of a corda contract you should be good just doing this for the contract interface.

```
class IOUContract : Contract {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        val IOU_CONTRACT_ID = "net.corda.training.contracts.IOUContract"
    }
```

You may want to also get the command interface as well.

good luck!